# RegEx: extract all text from link

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract ALL text from some kind of link

```
<Aid="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContentPlaceHolder_ResourceHostControl1_resContainer_rptColumn1_ctl00_ctl00_wrapper_downNodesTable_ctl01_ToolsetLink1"href="/Orion/NetPerfMon/NodeDetails.aspx?NetObject=N:78">SFTP</A>
```

the reason that the A and the id is as I removed all \t\r\n\ ans spaces

the expressions I tried :

```
\<a.+?>([^\<]+)
```

basically I want to extract the SFTP word that I guess is identified as:

start with `>` any possible character including +- dots commas end with `</a>`

after trying to use expresso

and browsing the values came to this :

```
>(\w+)\</a> - I get two values [0] -  >SFTP</A> [1] - SFTP
```

it works only for a word without any special chars

my problem is that I don't know what can be inside the > <

tried adding a `.` before the `\w+` as the "any character"

still with no success

Comment: Read this classical question and the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `string text = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=<a[^>]*>).*?(?=</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value`

Comment: Works GREAT !!! thank you , is there a chance that you will explain what does it mean ??

Comment: @Light_User I added the answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's bad to use Regex to parse html, but if you still want it.

```
string text = Regex.Match(html, "(?<=<a[^>]*>).*?(?=</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

We want to extract the text between `<a...>` and `</a>` tags, so we use positive lookbehind for `<a...>` tag, and positive lookahead for `</a>` tag. Text by itself is matched as `.*?`. How can we match `<a...>` tag? In place of `...` can be anything but `>`, so we use `[^>]*` making `<a[^>]*>` for us. Then we wrap it into lookbehind expression `(?<=<a[^>]*>)`. The `</a>` tag is wrapped into lookahead expression `(?=</a>)`. Then you combine all three into single one.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't remove the spaces, you could use an [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlTextReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid the problems with trying to parse XML with a regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static string GetText(string xmlFragment)
        {
            XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFragment, XmlNodeType.Element, null);

            while (tr.Read())
            {
                if (tr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    return tr.Value;
                }
            }

            return "";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "<A id=\"ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_BodyContent_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContentPlaceHolder_ResourceHostControl1_resContainer_rptColumn1_ctl00_ctl00_wrapper_downNodesTable_ctl01_ToolsetLink1\" href=\"/Orion/NetPerfMon/NodeDetails.aspx?NetObject=N:78\">SFTP</A>";
            Console.WriteLine(GetText(s)); // outputs "SFTP"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can because, the if "converting" to xml , the xml should be valid with all the beginnings and endings, or not ? it does have a <DIV id="some_id" , and I was thinking using HTMLAgilitypack and I didn't manage to extract the needed <DIV> .. so I trimmed the string between some 2 constant divs and extract the links from there

Comment: Yes, it would need valid XML. If you are already using string operations on the markup, you may end up with invalid parts. I suggest you keep trying with the HTMLAgilitypack route.

Comment: the output I get from the page as source are java scripts that eventually write "generated source" that I want to parse so I use 'string _Doc = web_Browser1.DocumentText' to get it , will it be valid ?

Comment: Well, as long as you take into account the remarks in [WebBrowser.DocumentText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you should get (at least mostly) valid markup. The HTMLAgilitypack should be fairly tolerant of markup errors.